# Visual Studio 2005 Not Loading

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, development-environment

After Visual Studio 2005 displays the splash screen it locks up on me.  No error, no cpu utilization, just a frozen splash screen.  I've tried it in both /safemode and /resetsettings

I'm sure it's one of the services on my machine, just wonder if anyone else has had the problem and can help me with the hunt?

BTW, it's works in a VM in the same machine.

Update: I finally tried something new, I started VS2005 in Windows compatibility 2000 mode, it starts then shuts down immediately.  I reset it to not run in compatibility mode and it starts right up.  grrrrr

I think it might be a profile issue, but the root cause is still unresolved.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins such as Resharper, viEmu, etc. loading at startup?

Comment: I've tried it in both /safemode and /resetsettings sorry should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running it in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) - if that doesn't let you sort it out you can try the /resetsettings switch, which has sorted out similar problems for me in the past.

/resetuserdata can also help.

Comment: VS 2005 was crashing for me every time it loaded (on my Windows 7 64-bit system).  I repaired the installation and ran in safe mode to no avail.  Running with the /resetsettings switch solved my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

look at the event log for you machine and see if VS threw any useful info in there; you may have to uninstall and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

I have VMWare installed on my machine. This was the cause of my problem!

I started VS2005 in Windows compatibility 2000 mode as suggested above - it started up then shut down immediately. I then ran without compatibility mode and VS2005 now runs perfectly!

I wasted half a day trying to sort this out!

Thank you for your post!

:)

Comment: The VMware Debugger add-in for VS is responsible for a major degradation in VS 2010 startup times. Uninstalling it (or better yet, not installing it in the first place) helps. So I guessing, maybe that's also the source of certain problems with VS 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up with the log command:

```
devenv.exe /Log c:\vs.log
```

And see if anything is noted in it.

Another thing to try is to run VS in a temporary user account to see if the problem is strictly with your user environment or is system-wide.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851477/visual-studion-2008-exits-as-soon-as-i-open-it/853198#853198).