# Visual studio 2008 exits as soon as I open it

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a problem with my Visual studion 2008.
It exits as soon as i open it.
I tried these options,
devenv /ResetSettings
devenv /SafeMode
devenv /resetuserdata
devenv /resetskippkgs

even i tried re-installing Visual Studion 2008.
Is there any way i can fix this issue.

thank you.
Prashant.

Comment: Do you have VS2008 SP1 installed?

Comment: nope.. I don't have SP1 installed.
And i get no error messages.
IDE just opens and stays for around 2 seconds and closes automatically.
Any work around for this???

Comment: Install SP1, it's a service pack you really should install when using 2008, as it's actually a service pack which contains fixes they should have added to the RTM version.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new user account and try using that in order to determine if the problem is due to your user environment or if the problem is system-wide.  If it does not occur with the new user, clear your regular user settings:

```
rd /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
rd /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
rd /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
```

(for XP, substitute "Local Settings" and "Application Data" for "AppData\Local" and "AppData\Roaming")

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon]
```

Answer (score 0):

What operating system?  If you are using Vista, try running devenv in Administrative mode, just to see what happens.

Comment: I am using MS Win Xp SP2
and I have the admin access to the system.